# What happened to logout?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

As of today, on my browser, the ability to logout has been removed.  Is this a glitch in my system or has it been moved to a new location? (windows 7 OS, IE 8)

Solved...see the comment below

Comment: I still have the option to log out on my user page on the main site, http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/681/dan-patterson

Comment: Andy
Figured it out, somehow that option got closed and I had to go to my profile and look for the every-so-small logout.  The next time, I opened my browser, everything was back to what it was before.  I still don't know how it vanished in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Log out was moved to the user page for now.

We may do something else in the future, but that is by far the least used item on the top nav and we need the room for long usernames.

Comment: Jeff, that is where I found it.  I just wondered where it was since I don't like to remain logged on all the time.